# .htaccess rewrite Cond http:// to add www Magento Multi Store

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I am using magento and I am having some problem when the user tries to access my website without www.
I am trying to force WWW to URL using htaccess.
My problem is that I tried lot of options I found but all of them work only parcially.

I made it work when user writes

> xyz.org
>
> xyz.org/page
>
> https:// xyz.org

But none of the solutions seems to redirect when the user types:

https:// xyz.org/page (with page route after and https:// before)

How can I Make this work? It would be nice to validate URL and not use wide range since I could still create subdomains like site.xyz.com and not insert www in front of it.

Below are some of the solutions I tried and didnt work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https:// www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?xyz.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// www.xyz.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.xyz\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// www.xyz.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In short words: I need to redirect https:// xyz.org/page to https:// [www.xyz.org/page](http://www.xyz.org/page) which doesnt seem to work at any of this options above

NOTE: SPACE AFTER // IS DUE TO NOT BEING ABLE TO POST LINKS

Thanks

Comment: To post links you need to enclose them in apostrophs, just as other inline code.

Comment: <del>apostrophes</del> <ins>backticks</ins>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after hours of investigation it ends up that magento was messing with redirects before the URL was rewritten inside htaccess. Thanks to this post that has enlighten me:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Admin-Configuration/PROBLEM-Auto-redirect-to-Base-URL-redirects-all-non-www-pages-to/m-p/460300#M4488

I found out that magento messes with redirects inside .htaccess, so the trick is to do any rewrite operation at the very beggining of the htaccess file, otherwise magento will mess with the rewrite and/or redirect user to home page. This could be also caused on multi store magento installations.

The following code at the very beggining of the file do the job:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Plus, activating Auto-redirect R301 to the main URL inside Configuration->Web